# Find words in a text file and retrieve adjacent number

Tags: regex, perl, wordsearch

I have a text file that contains words and numbers.

I would like to search for a key word and if the file contains that word search for a second word, if present I would like to extract the number next to the second word.

I would like to do this for two key words and two second words (i.e. the same thing twice, but different words each time).

I'd then like to put the numbers into an array and sort them numerically.

I've got so far but the output from array 1 changes when I join it to array 2 (some numbers are duplicated). I need a way to merge both operations.

```
my $filename;

my $filenamein = 'seq_id.txt';
open( my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $filenamein )
    or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";

while ( my $row = <$fh> ) {

    my $string = $row;

    my $startword = "16S ribosomal RNA";

    for ( $string =~ /$startword/ ) {

        my $word1 = "start:";
        $string =~ /$word1\s*?(\S+)/;
        my $next_word1 = $1;
        @w1 = ( $next_word1, );

        my $startword2 = "23S ribosomal RNA";

        for ( $string =~ /$startword2/ ) {

            my $word2 = "End";
            $string =~ /$word2\s*?(\S+)/;
            my $next_word2 = $1;
            @w2 = ( $next_word2, );
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think we're  going to need some sample input here.

Comment: Edit your question with input data and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

There's several problems with your code here, that means it's almost certainly not doing what you think.

First and foremost - turn on `use strict;` and `use warnings;`. This will warn you about some nasty things going on.

This for example:

```
for ( $string =~ /$startword/ ) {
```

`for` iterates a list. But `$string =~ /$startword/` isn't a list. It'll return a single value depending whether the match worked or not. That's at best a really ugly way of writing an `if` statement.

You've also got:

```
        my $word1 = "start:";
        $string =~ /$word1\s*?(\S+)/;
        my $next_word1 = $1;
        @w1 = ( $next_word1, )
```

What that is doing can be reduced to:

```
my ( $word1 ) = ( $string =~ /start:\s*(\S+)/ );
```

But then you are overwriting the list `@w1`, with a single element. Is that what you mean to do? You don't use `@w1` anywhere else.

What you have *currently* got could probably be reduced to:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $filenamein = 'seq_id.txt';
open( my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $filenamein )
    or die "Could not open file '$filenamein' $!";

while ( my $row = <$fh> ) {
    if ( $row =~ m/16S ribosomal RNA/ ) {
        my ($next_word1) = ( $row =~ /start:\s*?(\S+)/ );
        my @w1 = ( $next_word1, );
    }

    if ( $row =~ /23S ribosomal RNA/ ) {
        my ($next_word2) = ( $row =~ /End\s*?(\S+)/ );
        my @w2 = ( $next_word2, );
    }
}
```

You are also doing something quite strange with `@w1` and `@w2` - they are lists, but they're only ever getting assigned a single element. That is unlikely to be what you mean to do.

Answer (score 0):

many thanks for your help, really appreciate it. I realized I probably didn't know enough and got someone to help!

This seems to be working for me!

```
my $i;
my $filename;

my $filenamein = 'testin.txt';

open( my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $filenamein )
    or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";

while ( my $row = <$fh> ) {

    my $string = $row;

    my $startword = "16S ribosomal RNA";

    if ( $string =~ /$startword/ ) {

        my $word1 = "start:";
        $string =~ /$word1\s*?(\S+)/;
        my $next_word1 = $1;
        push( @w1, $next_word1 );

        print "Start @w1\n";

    }

    my $startword2 = "23S ribosomal RNA";

    if ( $string =~ /$startword2/ ) {

        my $word2 = "End";
        $string =~ /$word2\s*?(\S+)/;
        my $next_word2 = $1;
        push( @w2, $next_word2 );

        print "End @w2\n";

    }    # critical ender 2

}    #opener
```